# How to embed image in markdown file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, markdown

When I try to run images assets embed in markdown file doesn't get properly loaded, I am getting an exception:

> The following FileSystemException was thrown resolving an image codec:
> Cannot open file, path = 'assets/6507365313a339928af5313e92aaa14d.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

my code:

```
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';

  .....
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getFileData('assets/markdown_source_data.md'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text('Loading Markdown Info...');
              }
              return Markdown(
                data: snapshot.data,
                selectable: true,

      ....
  }
}
```

code image in markdown file:

```
![](assets/6507365313a339928af5313e92aaa14d.png)
```

pubspec.yaml
[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPWbQ.png)

markdown file content
[markdown content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S10IY.png)

Comment: please add a picture of your ```pubspec.yaml```

Comment: According to the documentation, you need to (a) add them to your assets, and (b) orefix if with `resource:`. _From image locations referring to bundled assets: Use an asset name prefixed by resource:. like resource:assets/image.png._

Comment: @Dolimight  i added two images to my question for more details

Comment: @RichardHeap i don't understand what i should do

Answer (score 0):

In your `pubspec.yaml` instead of

```
  assets:
    - assets/
```

you need to write

```
  assets:
    - assets/6507365313a339928af5313e92aaa14d.png
```

For each image you need to reference in your markdown, add a line of `assets`